# Capture FormulaChanged Event in Visio

Tags: vba, events, event-handling, shapes, visio

I'm new to doing VBA in Visio, and I'm having problems "getting" event-handling that isn't at the Document object level. Namely, I'm trying to capture the event that triggers when a Shape Data value is changed. I have the Visio 2010 SDK downloaded, and the related events are FormulaChanged and CellChanged. However, I don't know how to trigger on these events. I've gleaned from the internet that I need to use WithEvents and / or AddAdvise, but I can't seem to figure out how, even having gone through some SDK code examples.

How do I capture, in VBA, the FormulaChanged and/or CellChanged event(s) that trigger when I edit a Shape Data value for a shape?

Answer (score 1):

You have some options for triggering these events, as you seem to already realize:

1. use ThisDocument to store a WithEvents reference to the Visio Application, then catch all CellChanged and FormulaChanged events, and, when that runs, have your code decide if it's on a shape you're interested in.  This could have negative performance impacts, compared to 2:
2. You can set up a VBA class that just hooks a reference to a single shape, and watches for the Cell and Formula change events on that one shape.  You would instantiate an object for each shape whose value you want to watch.
3. You can also use ThisDocument (or any class module, but ThisDocument is a singleton so you don't have to instantiate it yourself) to watch all cell and formula change events on a single page.
4. Use the AddAdvise method (sample code here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms367505(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms367505%28v=office.12%29.aspx))

For 1-3, it's pretty simple to set up.  I've not tried 4 yet.

In the class/ThisDocument module:

```
Public WithEvents app As Visio.Application
Public WithEvents Pg As Visio.Page
Public WithEvents Shp As Visio.Shape

Private Sub app_CellChanged(ByVal Cell As IVCell)
    PrintCell Cell
End Sub

Private Sub app_FormulaChanged(ByVal Cell As IVCell)
    PrintCell Cell
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set app = Application
    Set Pg = ActivePage
    Set Shp = ActiveWindow.Selection(1)
End Sub

Private Sub Pg_CellChanged(ByVal Cell As IVCell)
    PrintCell Cell
End Sub

Private Sub Pg_FormulaChanged(ByVal Cell As IVCell)
    PrintCell Cell
End Sub

Private Sub Shp_CellChanged(ByVal Cell As IVCell)
    PrintCell Cell
End Sub

Private Sub Shp_FormulaChanged(ByVal Cell As IVCell)
    PrintCell Cell
End Sub

Private Sub PrintCell(Cell As Visio.Cell)
    Debug.Print Cell.Shape.ContainingPage.Name & "!" & Cell.Shape.Name
End Sub
```

I'm not sure that answers your question, but maybe it's a start.

Comment: I took your code and put it in the ThisDocument object. I added MsgBox "Test" to each one, so that I could get a dialog box. I then tried to edit some Shape Data. I can see FormulaChanged and CellChanged events, but nothing happens, neither through MsgBox or the debug message area. However, if I move a shape, Visio slows down, but maybe that is an Event Monitor issue.

Comment: Confirmed that moving a shape updates a bunch of cells and formulas, and my slow-down is from the Event Monitor. However, the above code never triggers for me (at least, nothing shows up in the debug window).

Comment: Did you run the class_initialize sub first?  This needs to run to set up the events..